# C# не видит перегрузку

Tags: c#, mvvm

Использую библиотеку `Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm`, во `ViewModel` наследуюсь от `ObservableObject` (в нем есть метод [`SetProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.componentmodel.observableobject.setproperty?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0#microsoft-toolkit-mvvm-componentmodel-observableobject-setproperty-1(-0-0-system-action((-0))-system-string)). По какой-то непонятной мне причине в документации и действительности перегрузки метода несколько отличаются, однако даже с теми что есть - невозможно перегрузить. Сигнатура метода  следующая:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T> (T oldValue, T newValue, Action<T> callback, string? propertyName = default);
```

Во ViewModel:

```
private bool _enableInbound;
public bool EnableInbound
{
    get { return _enableInbound; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _enableInbound, value, callback: new System.Action<bool>((target) =>
        {

        }));
    }
}
```

Но, при попытке использовать её вылезает вот такое как на скрине. Пробовал в `Action` передавать метод, так же пытался использовать просто лямбду без `new Action`, результат одинаковый. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки: `Error CS1615 Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword`

Comment: А что такое `_enableInbound`? (перепечатывание с картинки - жесть) Покажите код свойства и поля целиком и текстом. А лучше код класса. Текст ошибки тоже текстом приведите.

Comment: @aepot обновил вопрос и изменил ссылку на сетпроперти, не тот класс прикрепил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть же явная сигнатура, прямо в документации по вашей ссылке `SetProperty<T>(T, T, Action<T>, String)`. Почему вы думаете, что это можно использовать как `SetProperty<T>(ref T, T, Action<T>, String)`? Разница между `T` и `ref T` есть!

Вот все перегрузки, которые я вижу в этой библиотеке

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>([NotNullIfNotNull("newValue")] ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
protected bool SetProperty<T>([NotNullIfNotNull("newValue")] ref T field, T newValue, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
protected bool SetProperty<T>(T oldValue, T newValue, Action<T> callback, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
protected bool SetProperty<T>(T oldValue, T newValue, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action<T> callback, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
protected bool SetProperty<TModel, T>(T oldValue, T newValue, TModel model, Action<TModel, T> callback, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) where TModel : class
protected bool SetProperty<TModel, T>(T oldValue, T newValue, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, TModel model, Action<TModel, T> callback, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) where TModel : class
```

Среди них нет ни одной, где одновременно можно передать `ref` и колбэк. И самое главное - зачем вам там колбэк?

```
private bool _enableInbound;
public bool EnableInbound
{
    get => _enableInbound;
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref _enableInbound, value))
        {
            // вызвать колбэк или выполнить код можно прямо здесь
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не тот класс, я прикрепил ссылку не на те SetProperty. Оказывается ObservableObject есть и в других пространствах имен, я изменил ссылку в вопросе, посмотрите, там явно есть нужная мне (перегрузка)[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.componentmodel.observableobject.setproperty?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0#microsoft-toolkit-mvvm-componentmodel-observableobject-setproperty-1(-0-0-system-action((-0))-system-string)]. Но в целом решает вопрос, спасибо

Comment: @Aarnihauta дополнил вопрос в начале. Разница между `T` и `ref T` есть!

Comment: Да, действительно. Не заметил, что там без `ref`. Невнимательность) Спасибо!